# error in loop function

Tags: r, for-loop

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this code:

I have a folder where there are 12 tiff files names prec1.....prec12. I want to read each of them, multiply it by 1.0 and then save the raster.

```
library(raster)
for(i in 1:12){
  prec[i]<-raster("prec[i].tif")
  prec[i]<-prec[i]*1.0
  writeRaster(prec[i],"prec[i].tif",overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
`R:\rsrch\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\prec[i].tif' does not exist in the file system,
 and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

I have rechecked and my working directory is correct and all the tiff files are there.

Comment: You're naming all 12 of them the same thing - "prec[i].tif"

Comment: To clarify, anything in the `"..."` is taken literally. Your `i` won't loop, you;ll have to use `paste`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
prec[i] <- raster(paste0("prec", i, ".tif"))
```

Instead of

```
prec[i] <- raster("prec[i].tif")
```